# Recursive method doesn't work with FileWriter

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I have a method that should write down in a file a structure of a given directory in a tree view. But it doesn't write down subfolders and their files, so I tried adding a recursive call, but for some reason it doesn't work. How can i fix it?

```
public void readFiles() {
        File baseDirectory = new File(path);
        if (baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/info.txt")) {
                for (File file : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                        if (file.isFile()) {
                            writer.append(" |------ " + file.getName());
                            writer.append("\n");
                        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            writer.append(" |+++++ " + file.getName());
                            writer.append("\n");
                            path = file.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
                            readFiles(); // recursive call here

                        }
                }
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Main class :

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeViewer treeViewer = new TreeViewer();
        treeViewer.setPath("D:/test");
        treeViewer.readFiles();
    }
}
```

[Example of the output file: [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yznMt.png)

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see if it goes into the folders and does the recursive call?

Comment: The recursive call also executes `new FileWriter("D:/info.txt")` multiple times. This should probably not be part of the recursion but instead the writer should only be created once. Additionally the code would probably be better maintainable if the `path` was not a field but instead a parameter of the `readFiles` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void tree(File file, String indent, Writer out) throws IOException {
    out.write(indent + file.getName() + System.lineSeparator());
    if (file.isDirectory())
        for (File child : file.listFiles())
            tree(child, indent + "  ", out);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Writer out = new FileWriter("D:/info.txt")) {
        tree(new File("D:/test"), "", out);
    }
}
```